# I am trying to solve the problem regarding status code : 429

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, openai-api

Python Automation code using OpenAI API

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("prompt", help="The Prompt to send to OpenAI API ")
parser.add_argument("file_name", help="Name of the File")
args = parser.parse_args()

api_endpoints = "https://api.openai.com/v1/completions"
api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")

request_headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + api_key
}

request_data = {
    "model": "text-davinci-003",
    "prompt": f"Write python script for {args.prompt}. Provide only code, no text",
    "max_tokens": 100,
    "temperature": 0.5
}

time.sleep(5)

response = requests.post(api_endpoints, headers=request_headers, json=request_data)

if response.status_code == 200:
    response_text = response.json()["choices"][0]["text"]
    with open(args.file_name, "w") as file:
        file.write(response_text)
else:
    print(f"Request failed with status code : {str(response.status_code)}")
```

Error: Request failed with status code : 429

1. Free trial users 20 RPM
2. Added time limit
3. hide the API Key

Comment: First of all, you probably should not post your api token here ... And if the backend is telling you, that you are sending too many requests, you are probably sending too many requests and the only ways to resolve this is sending fewer requests or upgrading to a higher tier.  Just "changing the key" won't resolve your problem, because request limits are counted on an organizational level. I don't know what tier you are in, but on the free level with 20 requests per minute you hit that limit pretty fast ... https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/rate-limits/overview

Comment: okay what if set time limit into the code

Comment: Also check the body and headers of the response. There might be additional info in the response body explaining what limit you hit and there might be a `Retry-After` header which indicates when your next request may be possible ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting a maximum request limit in your code.
Assuming you can send 20 requests per minute on the free tier, say 15 for safety, you could send a request every 4 seconds.

```py
import time
print("start")
time.sleep(4) # this waits 4 seconds
# send request
```

Comment: done that but still same issue

Comment: I guess you could check your dashboard, you might have gone over some limit in place